# Remove-Mailbox Permissions in bulk

Tags: powershell

I've been asked to remove a user from mailbox full access permissions. I need this one for every mailbox in the company or specific users (around 180).

So that's what I did so far:

Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity "John Duo" -User "Nik Biessen" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All

This removes the delegation rights from one user. I need the same thing just for all mailboxes or a list of them to be executed in one script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you have one person that needs his acces rights removed from multiple mailboxes, or is there a list of users you need to remove?

Comment: Correct, one person that needs his access rights removed from multiple mailboxes.

Comment: Ok then. Do you have a list of mailboxes to check? What format?

Comment: Yes, I have exported the mailboxes using this :

Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission -User "Nik Biessen" | ft User,Identity,AccessRights | export-csv c:\users.csv

Comment: Just change `ft ...` into `Select-Object ...`. Format-* cmdlets are for **display** only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using a foreach loop.

Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |Foreach {Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.samaccountname -User "Nik Biessen" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All}

Hope Nik Biessen is the user who got access, which needs to be removed.
Please note that the csv file needs a header as ID in the first line.

Note - Code is not tested. Please test it before running it in a production environment.

Comment: Hi, I understand that I have to export my mailboxes first to the csv file. What do you mean a header as ID ? 
First I export all mailboxes that contain "Nik Baissen" in their full access :

Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission -User "Nik Baissen" | export-csv -path c:\Mailboxes.csv | ft User,Identity,AccessRights

When I look inside the file, I dont have "ID" column if that what you mean. I got RunspaceID

Comment: Hello, 
I think I confused you. Sorry for that.

The point what I was trying to convey is you need to have the list of mailboxes - either in a csv or piped from another query. Since you mentioned that this needs to be done for the entire mailboxes in your company, You can use get-mailbox commandlet itself and pipe the result to foreach loop. This loop will take each mailbox and process the remove-mailboxpermission commandlet. 

I have updated the actual response adjusting to this change.

Comment: So this is working : 
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |Foreach {Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.samaccountname -User "Nik Biessen" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -Confirm:$False}  I just added Confirm:$False to automate the answer of yes. Thank you Shabarinath!